# How to develop app for mutiple devices and versions in android

Tags: android, android-layout, version

I developed an application in galaxys version 2.3.3 and i want this app on galaxy tab also with same version what is step i have to follow can anybody help how to setup layout versions in xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provide lot of way for to do this, using below

For supporting all versions, you must set the API versions in manifest like

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="API version" />
<uses-sdk android:manSdkVersion="API version" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="API version" />
```

For supporting all devices, such as tablet also means you must create drawable folders like and place the images to this folders with needed size

```
res/drawable-ldpi
res/drawable-mdpi
res/drawable-hdpi
res/drawable-xhdpi
```

and also you must create the layouts like

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml
```

And refer below also

[Tips to Create Android app](http://danroundhill.com/2010/04/02/10-tips-for-developing-android-apps/)

Answer (score 4):

Go through the following links if you haven't already been through them:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: @ Rahul is it possible to release app for single device and single version in android...

Comment: @user1048958 sorry it is not possible.

Comment: I believe it is possible to release app for a single version of android. This can probably be done by: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" andrid:maxSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" /> by taking "7" as an example in the android manifest file. I'm not really sure about this though. However, releasing an app for a single device isn't possible.

Comment: +1 Rahul : android.os.Build.MODEL & android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER can also be used to control. When the app launches, check for Manufacturer an Model info.. If condition met then start the real application otherwise just tell user that you cant run the app.

Comment: @karthik shall i publish my app for galaxys and galaxysII with android 2.3.3 version....